# Twilio sms and call system and track the sms and call using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use twilio sms and call system and track the sms and call using codeigniter. When calling or sending sms want a response that will be stored in database. Is it possible to test using free(trial) account ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with free account, but you need to verify the number in your account before sending SMS/Call. I have implemented before.

Comment: Can I get any sample code or link? Actually when I am creating calling system it is okay. But I am unable to store the call status in database.So need suggestion.